# IOS: Allow SwipeToDelete But Don't Show Editing Button in Tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, delete-row

For a tableview, I want to allow SwipeToDelete and I also want to allow people to edit the tableview in the sense of being able to move rows up and down.  However, when moving rows up and down, I want to suppress the delete button as it is a bit distracting.

Is there a way to allow swipe to delete while suppressing the delete button in edit mode?

I am trying the following delegate but it is not doing the job:

```
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Detemine if it's in editing mode
        if (self.editing)
        {
NSLog(@"thinks it is editing");
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; //enable when editing mode is on
        }
        else {
NSLog(@"thinks editing mode is off");
          //  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
           return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
        }
    }
```

When I set the else to delete, it allows swipe to delete but also shows delete button.

When I set the else to None, it does not allow swipe to delete but does suppress delete button.

Some how self.editing is not doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for `editingStyle...` (to avoid showing the green `+` or red `-` buttons at the left of the cell when in edit mode.  Then you can return `YES` from `canEdit...` to indicate that the cell can still be edited (ie, deleted) by swiping:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

Optionally, you can also use the following to prevent the extra space appearing at the left of the cell during edit mode (where the `-` or `+` button would have otherwise been):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```